# Influence of quality of fish used to stock pond

Tags: the-sims-3

I have always stocked pond(s) in areas owned by my sim family as quickly as possible which often means low quality fishes are used. I recently spend a little more time stocking a pond with Perfect quality fishes though mostly are commonly found ones like Anchovy, Red herring etc.

I did not notice any difference from other ponds stocked with Normal-Outstanding fishes , but is there really none? Could there be hidden bonuses such as increased rate of bigger/higher quality fishes or chance of catching?

**Is there any bonus/reason to stock a pond with higher quality fishes?**